# click event on google maps marker not firing

Tags: google-maps

I have created a map using google maps that display great and shows all the markers that I want however the click event isn't firing, I can't see why I have changed script from being in the initialize function to the document ready in Jquery and reverted back again as it made no difference I moved the whole script from the header section to the bottom of the body that made no difference.

I am at a loss as what's wrong,  I would like to populate a div that will be at the side of the map with some text when the markers are clicked.

thanks for any assistance, I would have put this on a fork but for it to work it makes an ajax call for a xml file.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize()
    {
    var iconBase = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/102059869/'; //public drop box for icons
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.74,-2);//centres map around hull
    var myOptions = {zoom: 8,center: latlng,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};   
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);// Creates Map
    var mylatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.745670900000000000,-0.336741299999971500);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: mylatlng,map: map,title: 'Kingstown',  icon: iconBase + 'Kingstown_Logo.png'});// Creates Marker

            //Creates markers from data       
            $.get('PHP/SQL_MainData.php', function(d){
            $(d).find("marker").each(function()
                {
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng($(this).attr('latitude'),$(this).attr('longitude')); //gets Google LatLng
                    var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker(
                            {position: latlng,
                              map: map,
                              title:$(this).attr('traffic'),
                              icon: iconBase + 'caution.png'
                            }); 

                  marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: '<b>Info:</b> ' + $(this).attr('traffic')});

                 });
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        marker.info.open(map, marker);
                        $('#info-area span').text(marker.info);
                        });   
      }         
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google.maps.Marker is "myMarker"

You are adding the listener to marker (which is not a google.maps.Marker).

```
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng($(this).attr('latitude'),$(this).attr('longitude')); //gets Google LatLng
                var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker(
                        {position: latlng,
                          map: map,
                          title:$(this).attr('traffic'),
                          icon: iconBase + 'caution.png'
                        }); 

              marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: '<b>Info:</b> ' + $(this).attr('traffic')});

             });
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'click', function() {
                    marker.info.open(map, myMarker);
                    $('#info-area span').text(marker.info);
                    });
```